# How do I interpret significant Dunn's test results when the medians are the same?

Tags: nonparametric

Long time listener, first time caller...

So I am looking at data with five subgroups. Data is negatively skewed in the group as a whole and in all subgroups. Kruskal-Wallis tells me there is some difference between the groups. Following up, Dunn's test tells me that there is a  difference between groups 3 and the others -- group 1, in particular, at p<.00001. Groups 1 and 3 have the same median and SIQR.

In trying to make sense of this I have considered that group 3 is a good bit smaller than the others; and that group 3 is not quite as skewed.

On the other hand, I have also read that standard error should be calculated differently when there are tied ranks, versus when there are not. Being unsure which way the R implementation of the test was being conducted, I did a "by hand" experiment comparing the two different ways of figuring standard error. The significant difference disappeared when I took ties into account.

So the question: Is the difference I am observing more likely due to the different group size, distribution, or calculation of standard error?

Thanks, in advance, for your kind support.

Comment: Kruskal Wallis/Dunn's test doesn't compare medians ... so you shouldn't be interpreting it in terms of medians in the first place. It's no more relevant than if two means were the same but the result were significant.